# Typo3 10.4.1 Extension Builder: No tables created for new extension

Tags: typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x, extension-builder3

I have a TYPO3 10.4.1 installation (composer mode) on ubuntu 20.04 with php 7.4 and a mariadb database and installed the extension "Extension Builder" (v10-compatibility). When I create a new extension with domain model using the Extension Builder and save it there appears no errors, also when I add it to the composer.json and run the composer require command. However, there are no tables created in the database.

Does anyone has an idea where to start looking for the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: is file `ext_tables.sql` created with valid structure after saving in the Extension Builder? Also, go to mod Admin tools > Extensions and make sure that your new extension is enabled. Finally, go to Admin Tools > Maintenance and analyze a database.

Comment: The ext_table.sql was created with valid structure. The extension was enabled as well. Using the database anaylzer, I could now insert the tables into the database (Thanks for this hint!). This solution works now for me - but it should not be like this? It should be created automatically after saving the extension, right? Where could the problem then be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the extension "typo3_console" (`composer req helhum/typo3-console`) and then add this section in your composer.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "install-updateschema": [
        "typo3cms database:updateschema"
    ]
}
```

This will automatically update database schema with a composer install/update.

More information here : https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/typo3_console/5.6.0/CommandReference/Index.html